NAV2 SmacPlannerHybrid recalculates the path when it should not
I'm trying to configure the planner to generate only one path for the robot to follow, and to recalculate the path only if there are obstacles. Unfortunately, a new path is currently being calculated even when there are no obstacles.
At first, I thought the issue might be related to the behavior tree, but I'm unable to determine what might be wrong with it.
I have tried increasing cost scaling factor and it helped to reduce the frequency of unwanted path replanning but it has not eliminated the issue completely. Interestingly it can replan even in areas with very low cost like almost white-cost.
I would like to know if it’s possible to limit path recalculations without giving up replanning.
ROS VERSION: HUMBLE
NAV2 COMMIT: f79de33c
Thank you in advance for your help.
Example of my issue:

My behaviour tree:
  <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
    <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="6" name="NavigateRecovery">
      <PipelineSequence>
        <RateController hz="1.0" name="RateControllerComputePathToPose">
          <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="RecoveryComputePathToPose">
            <Fallback name="FallbackComputePathToPose">
              <ReactiveSequence name="CheckIfNewPathNeeded">
                <Inverter>
                  <GlobalUpdatedGoal/>
                </Inverter>
                <IsPathValid path="{path}"/>
              </ReactiveSequence>
              <ComputePathToPose goal="{goal}" path="{path}" planner_id="GridBased"/>
            </Fallback>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </RecoveryNode>
        </RateController>
        <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="RecoveryFollowPath">
          <FollowPath path="{path}" controller_id="FollowPath"/>
          <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Context" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
        </RecoveryNode>
      </PipelineSequence>
      <ReactiveFallback name="FallbackRecoveries">
        <GoalUpdated/>
        <RoundRobin name="RecoveryActions">
          <Sequence name="ClearingActions">
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </Sequence>
          <Wait name="WaitRecovery" wait_duration="5"/>
          <BackUp name="BackUpRecovery" backup_dist="0.5" backup_speed="0.5"/>
        </RoundRobin>
      </ReactiveFallback>
    </RecoveryNode>
  </BehaviorTree>
</root>

planner:
planner_server:
    ros__parameters:
        planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
        use_sim_time: True
        GridBased:
            plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid" # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
            downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
            downsampling_factor: 3              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
            tolerance: 0.2                      # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
            allow_unknown: true                 # allow traveling in unknown space
            max_iterations: 9000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
            max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
            max_planning_time: 15.0              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
            motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"    # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
            angle_quantization_bins: 72         # Number of angle bins for search
            analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
            analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0  # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
            analytic_expansion_max_cost: 200.0  # The maximum single cost for any part of an analytic expansion to contain and be valid, except when necessary on approach to goal
            analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: True  #  Whether or not to override the maximum cost setting if within critical distance to goal (ie probably required)
            minimum_turning_radius: 6.        # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
            reverse_penalty: 3.5             # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
            change_penalty: 0.3                # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
            non_straight_penalty: 1.0         # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
            cost_penalty: 3.5                 # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
            retrospective_penalty: 0.015
            lookup_table_size: 50.0             # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
            # Size, in costmap pixels, of the each lookup table dimension to populate
            cache_obstacle_heuristic: True     # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
            debug_visualizations: False         # For Hybrid nodes: Whether to publish expansions on the /expansions topic as an array of poses (the orientation has no meaning) and the path's footprints on the /planned_footprints topic. WARNING: heavy to compute and to display, for debug only as it degrades the performance.
            use_quadratic_cost_penalty: False
            downsample_obstacle_heuristic: False
            allow_primitive_interpolation: True
            smooth_path: True                  # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path
            smoother:
                max_iterations: 1000
                w_smooth: 0.1
                w_data: 0.2
                tolerance: 1.0e-10
                do_refinement: true
                refinement_num: 2


Replanning occurs in the Behavior Tree, there's no automatic replanning in the smac planners or in the planner server writ large. So the two questions I have are:

Have you validated your BT? It seems to me most likely that your BT is not correctly doing what you want it to do.
Have you validated that your BT is being loaded and not using the default?


The behavior tree (BT) is loaded correctly because when I comment out , a single path is generated, and it is not recalculated during traversal (changing the destination in RViz triggers replanning as intended). Based on this, I am searching for an error in the source code of IsPathValid, but at first glance, I didn't find any issues. It likely requires further debugging. I currently plan to check the version from the main branch, where the IsPathValid code has been significantly modified.
